# Accessing Table without primary Key -Spring data jpa

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring data jpa and I have to port an existing application to Spring boot.

I am encountered with the database table which does not have the primary key column. How can I write the entity without @Id annotation.

If am trying, I am getting error :

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.example.domain.Employee
    at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.getElementsToProcess(InheritanceState.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:775) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3845) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3799) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1412) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1846) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
```

Is there any way to use this without modifying the existing database?

Answer (score 2):

yes, using @IdClass annotation.

```
@Entity
@IdClass(EmployeeKey.class)
public class Employee {
   @Id
   private int id;
   @Id
   private int departmendId;

}


public class EmployeeKey implements Serializable {
   private int id;
   private int departmendId;
}


public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, EmployeeKey>,{}
```

Answer (score -2):

Even if the underlying table does not have an explicit primary key specified, I am sure there is at least one column that is defined as unique (or has a unique index specified for it).

You can add the @Id annotation to the entity field relevant to that column and  that will the sufficient for the persistence provider. You probably would not want to specify any generator of course.

If you happen to have a few unique columns which could form a sort of natural key then you can specify a composite key using the `@EmbeddedId` strategy or the `@IdClass` strategy in your entity.